# Magento 2 integration

Tags: magento2, integration

How can I integrate the frontend and backend parts? 
how to give arguments to block and how to take it from the template?
Is there any good material? 
thanks

Comment: what you actally want to do create a scenario in magento  i woud be much better..

Comment: I am creating a popup , I have frontend and backend part now want to integrate and It will be like mageplaza better popup, It must take styles from the backend , It will be just newsletter but they will be able to change style and text from backend whenever they want